# How to implement iOS keyboard number pad?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm making a custom keyboard so at first wanna make the one similar with real iOS keyboard.

On the iOS keyboard when I tap [123] button, the alphabet keys changes to number keys. THIS is what I want to do.

Is there any special ways for this?

Comment: Just set keyborad style as numberpad in your stotyboard. If you want to add your own style then use keyboard extension e.g. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344   http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/  https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

> self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

Comment: could you explain more? how to set keyboardType??

Comment: i'm added keyboard target and added view(xib)

Comment: You need to pull a IBOOutlet from the textFild at your xib file, to the class. So you hold a "textFiled" property. Then you can use the code above. Good luck